# Split a UTC time format to required format in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have UTC timestamp like this

```
2017-09-21T11:34:40Z[UTC]
```

I want the format like this

```
2017-09-21T11:34:40Z
```

Comment: You just want to remove `[UTC]`?

Comment: Yes @Commercial Suicide

Answer (score 1):

you pass like this get above format

```
moment.utc().format();
```

Comment: But bro it doesn't remove [UTC]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` in your case and remove characters from the end of the date, like this:

```js
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 1, 2, 12, 35, 40));
date = date.toUTCString().slice(0, -4);
console.log(date)
```